# How to "out" an array of strings and pass it through into a listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox, out

This is a part of UpdateGUI():

```
DisplayOptions choice = (DisplayOptions)comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(choice, out strSeatInfoStrings);
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(strSeatInfoStrings);
```

The compiler is complaining about this row (And the parameter of the last row):

```
seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(choice, out strSeatInfoStrings);
```

What I'm trying to do is to take an array (strSeatInfoStrings) and put it inside a listbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use `out` instead of just returning the array from the method?

Comment: What error message do you get from the compiler?

Comment: Yes I need to use out...

The error message I got is: #1"The name 'strSeatInfoStrings' does not exist in the current context"
#2"The best overloaded method match for 'Assignment3.SeatManager.GetSeatInfoStrings(Assignment3.DisplayOptions, out string[])' has some invalid arguments"
#3"Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out strSeatInfoStrings' to 'out string[]'"

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the declaration of that variable before the call:

```
DisplayOptions choice = (DisplayOptions)comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
string[] strSeatInfoStrings;
seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(choice, out strSeatInfoStrings); 
listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
listBox1.Items.AddRange(strSeatInfoStrings);
```

The other oppinion is to change the signature of your method and return the values, so you can write this

```
DisplayOptions choice = (DisplayOptions)comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
listBox1.Items.Clear(); 
listBox1.Items.AddRange(seatMngr.GetSeatInfoStrings(choice));
```

Comment: I have already decleared the "string[] strSeatInfoStrings;" in the GetSeatInfoStrings method inside the seatMngr object.

When I tried the first suggestion i got "Nullreferenceexception was unhandled"

And the second suggestion got me "Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\Kalle\Desktop\Assignment4-hjälp\Assignment4\Assignment3\MainForm.cs 153 13 Assignment4"

And some other problems..

Comment: If you declare it inside the method `GetSeatInfoStrings` then this is the wrong scope. Declare it in the way I showed you in my sample above and simply use the out parameter in your method `GetSetInfoStrings` and you will see - it works.

Comment: I did and it gave me the following two errors #1"Use of unassigned out parameter 'strSeatInfoStrings'"     #2"The out parameter 'strSeatInfoStrings' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method"

Comment: You have to set the value of an out parameter before you leave the scope of your method. So in case there is a if-statement and you only set the out parameter there, you have to initialize it in the else part too.

Answer (score 0):

This smells more like a code design issue. The method name `GetSeatInfoStrings` clearly expresses that it returns some strings. Based on your use of the method, it looks like it's declared like so:

```
public void GetSeatInfoStrings(string choice, out string[] result)
```

In my opinion, it would be far better to declare it like this instead:

```
public void IEnumerable<string> GetSeatInfoStrings(string choice)
```

...and just return the array from the method as you normally would. The primary uses for `out`, as I see it is when you need to return more than one value from the method. The `Int32.TryParse` method is a great example; the method returns a `bool` indicating success, and the `out` parameter will contain the result.

In your case it seems as if you have one result, so using `out` will only be confusing.